# Стили палитры цветов <input type="color">

Tags: html, css, input

Добрый день! Интересует, можно ли задать стили, а именно расположение для палитры цветов `<input type="color">`

```css
body{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="color"> выберите цвет
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, с помощью любого `color picker`. Например [Huebee](http://huebee.buzz/), [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3), [jquery-palette-color-picker](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carloscabo/jquery-palette-color-picker/master/demo.html), [ColorPanel](https://infario.github.io/colorpanel/), [color-picker](https://rawgit.com/tovic/color-picker/master/color-picker.picker-set.html) или любой другой на ваш вкус.

Без скриптов стилизовать, к сожалению, не получится.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.